# reformat spark-streaming dstream count with print

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I use this line to print a message off my RDD count:

```
myDStream.count.print
```

I get something like:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501499254000 ms
-------------------------------------------
2

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501499256000 ms
-------------------------------------------
0

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501499258000 ms
-------------------------------------------
0
```

I simply would like to reformat this message like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501499254000 ms
-------------------------------------------
log.info Got new batch with 2 messages

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501499256000 ms
-------------------------------------------
log.info Got new batch with 0 messages

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1501499258000 ms
-------------------------------------------
log.info Got new batch with 0 messages
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [implementation of `print`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala#L738) is fixed. If we would like to have a different output, we need to roll our own implementation:

```
dstream.foreachRDD{(rdd, time) =>
    val count = rdd.count()
    println("-------------------------------------------")
    println(s"Time: $time")
    println("-------------------------------------------")
    println(s"log.info Got new batch with $count messages")
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but before validation, do I will slow my process making a count every 2 sec (batchInterval = 2). I need to process a lot of data and I wonder if I will create a bottleneck with this approach?

Comment: @a.moussa `print` to the console is usually for initial exploration and debugging purposes. I would not recommend it for anything else.

Comment: so, is this a good solution to insert my message (containing count) into mapr db to monitor my application in production?

Comment: @a.moussa definitively *not*.  You should save the stream to the DB instead (Look it up. There are many resources dealing with that out there)